# SharePoint and Javascript - Get content types for list

Tags: javascript, client-object-model

I have been using the JSOM with SharePoint 2013 and am trying to get the content types of a list to iterate through, and am having no luck.

First, while the success handler is being reached, the oTargetCTypes variable never seems to be populated. Secondly, I occasionally get an exception thrown when a null id somewhere attempts to have the toString method called.

I see nothing wrong with this code, but if someone sees something I dont I would appreciate the assist!

```
function addIfPollList(listId, webId) {
this.optionListId = listId;
this.optionListTitle = listTitle;
this.optionWebId = webId;

this.clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
this.oTargetList = clientContext.get_site().openWebById(this.optionWebId).get_lists().getById(optionListId);
this.oTargetCTypes = this.oTargetList.get_contentTypes();

this.clientContext.load(oTargetCTypes);
this.clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
Function.createDelegate(this, isPollListSuccessHandler),
Function.createDelegate(this, isPollListErrorHandler)
);
}

function isPollListSuccessHandler() {
cTypeEnumerator = this.oLists.getEnumerator();
}

function isPollListErrorHandler() {}
```

Comment: I don't know if this helps or not but does your app need full control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your success function you are trying to access `oList` which I guess is not correct. function `addIfPollList` loads content type in `oTargetCType` object, hence I believe it should enumerated in success function.

```
function addIfPollList(listId, webId) {
    this.optionListId = listId;
    this.optionListTitle = listTitle;
    this.optionWebId = webId;

    this.clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    this.oTargetList = clientContext.get_site().openWebById(this.optionWebId).get_lists().getById(optionListId);
    this.oTargetCTypes = this.oTargetList.get_contentTypes();

    this.clientContext.load(oTargetCTypes);
    this.clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, isPollListSuccessHandler),
        Function.createDelegate(this, isPollListErrorHandler)
    );
}

function isPollListSuccessHandler() {
    //cTypeEnumerator = this.oLists.getEnumerator();
    //I guess you need access this.oTargetCTypes as you are loading it in above function
    cTypeEnumerator = this.oTargetCTypes.getEnumerator();
}

function isPollListErrorHandler() {}
```